# Fibonacci sequence using recursion in C

Tags: c

I am trying (and failing) to print the fibonacci sequence using recursion. I'm sure this is very very basic but I can't seem to get it. 
Please tell me what I am doing wrong, thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fib(int a, int i)
{
    int nextnum, num1 = nextnum - 1, num2 = nextnum - 2;
    for (i = 0; i >= a; i++) {
        nextnum = num1 + num2;
        printf("%d", nextnum);
        i++;
        fib(a, i);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int a, i = 0;

    printf("Enter a number for fib series: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    if (a == 1 || a == 2) {
        printf("Enter higher number please!\n");
    }
    else {
        fib(a, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about returning a value from your function?

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and read them.

Comment: You can use iteration (for loop) or you can use recursion to make your code do all the numbers it is supposed to. I think you are trying to do both at the same time.

Comment: [Recursive Fibonacci Method Explained](https://medium.com/launch-school/recursive-fibonnaci-method-explained-d82215c5498e)

Comment: @ryyker nonsense. `if (a==1 || a==2)` does exactly what is naturally expected, it  is true if a is either 1 or 2.

Answer (score 3):

Fibonacci numbers are often used as an intro into recursion because they are naturally recursive. In fact, implementing them recursively is trivial in any language. On a side note, it is usually not the best way to implement Fibonacci sequence for practical purposes.

By definition, Fib(X) = Fib(X - 1) + Fib(X - 2). This is recursion right there. The only thing which is missing is how we stop the recursion, and we know that Fib(0) is the same as Fib(1) and is 1.

How do we translate this to the C language? Very simple, almost one-to-one mapping!

```
unsigned int fib(unsigned int k) {
    // First, check our exit (stop) conditions:
    if (k == 0 || k == 1) return 1;

    // Now recursive part  
    return fib(k - 1) + fib(k - 2);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I believe your statement that _Fib(0) is the same as Fib(1)_ is not necessarily true.  Optionally, the zeroth term can be `0`.  If user desired to implement algorithm for zeroth term == 0, the fix would be to change the exit criteria to: `if (k == 0 || k == 1) return k;`. ( _[referring to this site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)_. )

Answer (score 2):

Almost every recursion function contains two part : the particular part and then the recursive part.

So to write this function your algorithm will look like this

```
 if (condition_separate_particular_part) 
    {
        //here the code for part
    }
else 
    {
         //the recursive part 
    }
```

Now to determine the recursive part you will try to find how to explain the element "i" using it's predecessor elements "i-1" "i-2" ....

Like this it will be easy for you every time.

Note that sometimes it's useful to start to find iterative way to make it easy for your self.

I'm damn sure that you are new so that's why you feel lost a bit. But trust me you will habit soon if you exercise more. Try and you gonna see. ;).

Let me know if you find difficulties to find more exercises/examples. I will try to help you :).

[Here](https://www.w3resource.com/c-programming-exercises/recursion/index.php) is and example. Just type Exercise with solution for recursive functions on C and you will find a lot to exercise ;).

Now here both recursive and iterative code

Recursive

```
 int fib(int n){
      if (n < 2) // here is particular case
        return n;
      else  // here is the recursion 
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    }

printf("%d\n", fib(10));
```

iterative

```
int fib(int n) {
  int first = 0, second = 1;

  int tmp;
  while (n--) {
    tmp = first+second;
    first = second;
    second = tmp;
  }
  return first;
}
```